# Markdown with Prompt Choice

Tags: markdown, botframework

With the Bot Framework, I tried to use Markdown content on a PromptDialog.Choice, but it appears to be impossible (at least on the emulator).

Has someone succeed with it ? Or at least, just add a break line (\n\n doesn't work also...) ?

This code give me:

```
PromptDialog.Choice(
    context,
    AfterResetAsync,
    new string[] { "FIRST", "LAST" },
    "This **is** a Markdown \n\n sentence",
    promptStyle: PromptStyle.Keyboard);
```

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Could you post your code? I'm not having any trouble getting Markdown to work with Prompts.choice, and adding new lines works with \n\n. Are you using C# or Node.js?

Comment: @mgbennet I'm using C#...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cards do not currently support markdown so this is impossible. I would expect that this will be part of an update at a later time, but I do not know for sure. Right now your only option is to format on the front-end side, such as if you are using a web chat interface you can use javascript or css to directly style the chat. I had to use this method on a card by checking for the card's innerhtml and then applying my styling to that element.